# Laravel yoeunes/toastr getting white background and white text

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, toastr

I am using laravel 7. Here I used yoeunes/toastr ( https://packagist.org/packages/yoeunes/toastr ) . But the background color of the toastr and text color is white. also tried other toastr also. Happening the same thing. When I am removing all my layouts file ( js,jquery,css linked header file) the toastr works fine .but with the layouts file the toastr is not working.

[image: here is the alert]

I used the code as documantation

Comment: There is a possibility that any of your other js code have toastr settings initialized. Do you use any other packages?

Comment: "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.6",
        "brian2694/laravel-toastr": "^5.54",
        "bumbummen99/shoppingcart": "^3.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^2.0",
        "melihovv/laravel-shopping-cart": "^7.0" @iamab.in

Comment: check if any of the packages uses the `toastr` and initialize its settings?

Comment: can't get you. how can I check that? @iamab.in

Comment: As you say, `When removing layouts file ( js,jquery,css linked header file) the toastr works fine`, the linked js/jquery might have initialized the toastr settings. So from your code editor, search fro the word `toastr` in those js, jquery files.

Comment: use `@toastr_css` before close `</head>` and use ` @jquery  @toastr_js @toastr_render` before other js. This way it works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use @toastr_css after your  **layouts file ( js,jquery,css linked header file)** .
After extending layout use the @toastr_css in the section part like this

```
 @extends('layouts')
 @section('content')
 @toastr_css
 ....your code....
 
 @jquery
 @toastr_js
 @toastr_render
 @endsection
```

then it will not affect your layout file

Comment: this fixed mine, just put toastr.css at the last part. it turned-out that the css was overridden by other css files. `[+1]`

Answer (score 1):

As alternative you can use in your site.css the following code:

```
/***toastr - NOTIFICATION **************************************************/

.toast-success {
    background-color: #51a351 !important;
}

.toast-error {
    background-color: #bd362f !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.css" integrity="sha512-vKMx8UnXk60zUwyUnUPM3HbQo8QfmNx7+ltw8Pm5zLusl1XIfwcxo8DbWCqMGKaWeNxWA8yrx5v3SaVpMvR3CA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

Put the css for the toastrjs at the bottom of the page.As @kapitan has stated in the comments *turned-out that the css was overridden by other css files.*